# Does 'reloading' a server reset dns/email settings

Tags: linux, dns, vps, cpanel

I have a client with web hosting on a Linux VPS. Unfortunately, I know very little about VPS hosting and am having a hard time finding information on how to set up email and DNS records. So the best option for right now is to purchase a Cpanel license for one month in order to set this up.

However, since the Cpanel charge is monthly, and my client does not want to pay the ongoing cost, I assume the web host will forcibly remove cpanel once the subscription is cancelled. Since Cpanel can only be removed by 'reloading' the server, does this mean that any email/dns configuration I have made will be lost?

Comment: Does "reload" mean "reboot" or does it mean "wipe and reprovision"? Have you considered asking your service provider what happens at the end of a CPanel contract term?

Comment: I'm getting this from https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-to-uninstall-cpanel.143557/ where a cpanel moderator says, "You'll probably need to reload the server itself, there is no way to remove cPanel." Honestly I wasn't sure where to ask. I figured the web host support would be reluctant to help me understand if I can get out of paying them for something. If I understand the situation a little better, at least I can ask a more specific question.

Comment: According to the link you've provided in the comment, "reload" means "wipe and reprovision". Which in turn answers your main question.

Comment: I assume that you are implying that all email configuration/DNS records made on the Cpanel _will_ be removed with a "wipe and reprovision"?

Comment: Reprovisioning will erase everything on the system. If you've configured anything there it will get erased

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never heard removal of cPanel requiring reloading of the server but I think it is safe to assume that, it is the hosting company's prerogative. If what they mean by reloading is reinstalling the OS on the server, the answer is, yes, it will remove whatever you have done on this server.

Having said that, it is very hard for me to understand what the purpose of this server is and why the email and DNS records changing with the server reloading. I am not saying this is out of norm, but, if I think I know what you mean by DNS record and email settings, they need to be updated at the DNS provider, not on your server, i.e., reloading the server has nothing to do (unless your server is being used as a DNS server at the same time) with these settings. Also, if this is the case, cPanel, will not be much of help other than one concentrated point of management.

What you need is the tool that your domain registrar provides, which helps you set up these settings. If you used a company, who said "free domain registration, with 1 year prepaid hosting agreement" or something similar to that, then, they are the ones who provide the DNS management tools. And if your client is going to be an ongoing client that you will support, you have two choices: (1) learn how to use their individual tools, or (2) pay for the ongoing cPanel subscription, out of the maintenance fee you are charging them. I suggest option (1) but to each his or her own.

Comment: Cpanel usually has something called "the advanced dns zone editor", and controls for setting up email accounts. I wasn't aware that DNS records were provided separately, but I assumed this was through the hosting rather than the domain. I guess this explains why I couldn't find any information on changing DNS records on a VPS. The domain is with my client's old web developer, therefore I don't really have access to the domain registrar. I think I at least understand what I've been missing now